# How to add a node field to a database table in a custom module

Tags: 7, database, installation

When I am writing my own custom module, and designing a database table, if I want to use the  field `nid` to refer to a node, because I want my module to adding something to each node, how should I implement this in the module's mymodule.install file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time you will probably want to use the field API (CCK module in D6) rather than adding custom tables or modifying node by yourself.

Adding custom tables was a very D5 way of doing thing.

If you want to do this you will need to define your tables using [`hook_schema()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--install.php/function/hook_schema/6) and then in your mymodule_install() hook you can call [`drupal_install_schema()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_install_schema/6) this should create a new table which represents your module.

It is worth mentioning that your schema should always represent your current schema. If you add a column you should alter the schema so that someone who installs your module will get the correct schema, but also write an update function to alter the table so that existing users get the correct new schema.

It is possible to alter other modules' tables, but I think that should be covered in another question.

Comment: i only want to add two fields to the specific content type's node.if don't creat the table,which table should i add. someone tell me to use the node_revision table.what do you think?

Comment: If you only want to add two fields to a specific node type use the field api.

Comment: how to use the field api. could you make me an example.thank you.

Comment: I could, but it may be better to ask a separate question. As you are specifically asking about database tables in your question.