# How to add a date field to content type without installing the date module?

Tags: entities, datetime

I want to define a new field with **date type** and add it to content type by code.

But I don't want to install [date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) module. I want to add a field same as **published on** field when we are editing a content.

Is there any way to do this or it is impossible?

Comment: [How to add a node field to a database table in a custom module](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2315/how-to-add-a-node-field-to-a-database-table-in-a-custom-module) and [db_add_field](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_add_field/7)

Comment: I want to define a date field and use it in different content types. Please tell me is it possible with article that you have inserted it's link ?

Comment: No, for that you will need field Api. Here is tutorial: [Poutine Maker: An Introduction to the Field API in Drupal 7 (Part 1)](http://evolvingweb.ca/story/poutine-maker-introduction-field-api-drupal-7-part-1)